# Combining Jar file with -classpath JAVA

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have a question regarding compiling a class which has some dependent classes in a Jar file (`MyJar.jar`). By putting a directory tree in a -classpath option (ex: `javac -cp MyJar MyClass.java` ), will all the subdirectories be checked for classes or only the top level classes in the directory tree?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edited as requested. Hope now is clear that I use a Jar as classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

will the directories specified with `-cp` be recursivly searched: No

when the classloader enters a directory specified in the classpath it starts using the `package` where the class is located as subdirectory. if no package is specified then the classloader will expect it under the immediate children (class files) of the directory.

It's a combination of `-cp` direcoties/jars and `package name`.

Lets say you have the following directory structur

```
+ Project
    sayhello.jar
    + dir
        + sub
            + com
                + test
                    SayHelloMain.java
```

Where the code of the class `SayHelloMain.java` is (**note the package declaration**)

```
package com.test;

import miscellaneous.so.SayHello;

public class SayHelloMain {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SayHello.sayIt();
   }
}
```

and the jar file `sayhello.jar` containing the class `SayHello`

this is how you'll have to compile the class `SayHelloMain` if the command line is opened in the same directory as the java source file

```
javac SayHelloMain.java -cp ..\..\..\..\sayhello.jar
```

or if the command line is opened in the the dierctory `Project`

```
javac dir\sub\com\test\SayHelloMain.java -cp sayhello.jar
```

Let's say u have opened a command line in the dierctory `Project`

This is how you can run the class `SayHelloMain`

```
java -classpath dir\sub;sayhello.jar com.test.SayHelloMain
```

the class name has to be **fully qualified** thus `com.test.SayHelloMain`

The command

```
java -classpath dir;sayhello.jar com.test.SayHelloMain
```

will no work since the direcotry `dir` is not recursively searched

the command

```
java -classpath dir;sayhello.jar sub.com.test.SayHelloMain
```

will also not work since there is no such package `sub.com.test`. A package is only that defined in the package declaration of a class

Comment: I gave you only 1 point for your answer as I do not have the right to give more yet. Thanks a lot for the thorough response.

Answer (score 0):

If your directory tree represents packages, then all your classes will be loaded and usable.

For example, the following class:

```
package my.company.project;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

Should be inside the folder *my/company/project* to be usable.