# Java, basic class path problems

Tags: java

I've been writing simple programs in Java, but seem to run into problems where the class path is involved.

My compiled class files exists in the directory:  `/home/pi/code/java/eclipse/bin/`

When in this directory I can run "java Controller" and the program will run.

Experimenting with the class path I tried the following:`"java -cp /home/pi/code/java/ eclipse.bin.Controller"`

But I get the following exception:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: eclipse/bin/Controller (wrong name: Controller)
"
```

The weirdest thing is that Java even constructed the final section `"eclipse.bin.Controller"`, e.g. I could tab it when i was typing the command, so I expected this to work.

My end goal is to point the class path at a JDBC driver.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The explanations [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131498/combining-jar-file-with-classpath-java) may help you I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java -cp /home/pi/code/java/eclipse/bin Controller
```

Would be the right way if you have your `Controller` class in the default package.

If you try to refer to your class as `eclipse.bin.Controller` the Java runtime will look for the `Controller` class within the package `eclipse.bin` and packages are not directories.

Comment: Xerphiel, packages and the classpath are tricky to get to the bottom of, and you will have some frustration handling them. They are however required knowledge for a Java programer. They are kind of the linker configuration for Java if you know C/C++, although not *that* frustrating in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've looked at some tutorials but nothing is making huge amounts of sense (although it is late). Any good tutorials would be greatly appreciated!