# java classpath and package issues

Tags: java

I have a simple MyHelloWorld.java file within a directory myhelloworld. I set the classpath to appropriate direcotries by exporting CLASSPATH='[some needed class]' in my ~/.bashrc file. and I still need to use javac MyHelloWorld.jaca -cp 'the above classpath' to compile the .java file.

So here's my first question, why do I still need to explicitly set classpath by having a -cp option given the CLASSPATH is already specified?

After the file was compiled, I saw no file like MyHelloWorld, but the java commmand can autocomplete 'java MyHelloWorld' when in fact there's no file named MyHelloWorld exists within the directory? (If I typed "java MyH", the command can be automatically completed).

When I tried to execute 'java MyHelloWorld', it prompted me there's NOClassDefFoundError, which was an indicator of missing library. However when I tried to do 'java -cp  MyHello', The command wouldn't complete itself, suggesting it couldn't find anything executable at all

So what are the reasons for above confusing signs. Can anyone take from here and explain to me how java deal with classpath and package, etc. Thanks!

Comment: "I have a simple MyHelloWorld.java file within a directory myhelloworld" - the classpath should contain **compiled** classes.

Comment: to generates .class files into a directory, you must use javac -d option.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, cool but why do I still need to specify -cp option when I had already set CLASSPATH in my .bashrc file

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand your description of your problem.  But in summary, compile your .java to .class, ensure your .class files are somewhere known, add that known location to your classpath, and then run `java`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, in simple words, will doing "export CLASSPATH=[some needed files path]" do the same work as specifying a -cp option?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131498/combining-jar-file-with-classpath-java), it might have some useful infos for you.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [java tuturial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) and especialy [this section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/unix.html).

The [section about JARs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html) is for you too.